# Bootstrap 3 Collapse Button not displaying content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Usually I find answers for my issues without posting, but not today.

I'm building a website with bootstrap 3 and a mod from www.bootswatch.com, my navbar is ok, the collapse button is showing but once you click on it the menu is not being displayed. I'm new to bootstrap, so I might be making some silly mistake. Here's the code (I'm placing all of it because it may be missing some .js file (?)):

Head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Escola Artes e Letras</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li>a escola</li>
                <li class="mleft40">educação</li>
                <li class="mleft40">cardápio</li>
                <li class="mleft40">calendário</li>
                <li class="mleft40">instalações e segurança</li>
                <li class="mleft40">fotos</li>
                <li class="mleft40">contato</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Bottom:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your local CSS and JS files are found and loaded? Also, what happens if you use the Bootstrap CDN for the CSS and JS instead? You can find them here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/.

Comment: Hi chrsva! Thank you so much. It worked with the CDN for the JS. And then when I looked at my js folder I realized that it was empty. I knew it was a silly mistake like this! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running a custom build of Bootstrap or have other pressing reasons to serve local files, a best-practice is to use a CDN for your Bootstrap dependencies. You can find it here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Add them to your refs like you would a normal file:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/x.x.x/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/x.x.x/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This not only ensures that you are using the correct files - it further reduces the load on your server, since the files will be delivered to your clients from elsewhere.